# Is it possible to quickly export a .jpg and .png simultaneously in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, jpeg, png

I work with product images for an online retail site. Each product image needs to have a .jpg copy and .png copy. Currently, I just export once as .jpg and then export again as .png. This is both time-consuming and I often forget one of the file types. Is it possible to have a quick export that creates both filetypes simultaneously?

I haven't found anything like this on the web, other than batch processing multiple image files which isn't what I'm looking for.

Comment: Not sure, but the guys over on https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/ might have a better idea if you don't get anything from here.

Comment: Sounds like a job for Actions (which are only available on full Photoshop, not Photoshop Elements).

Answer (score 1):

You can record Photoshop actions that you can later play as many times as you like.
This records everything that you do, including calling *File > Save As*.

Specifically for *Save As*, when recording do not change the filename.
If you enter a new filename, that new name is recorded and used each time you
run the action, which may defeat the purpose.
The same goes if you navigate to a different folder than that of the image.

Useful references:

- [Create actions in Adobe Photoshop](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/creating-actions.html)
- [How to Automate Your Workflow in Adobe Photoshop](https://www.howtogeek.com/166973/how-to-automate-your-workflow-in-adobe-photoshop/)

Answer (score 0):

This could definitely be done with ExtendScript, which is Adobe's version of JavaScript used for automating almost anything you can think of within Photoshop, Illustrator, etc.

Think of ExtendScript like the bigger, more powerful brother of Actions within Photoshop. (Actions have limitations - for example I believe you can only transform size based on % values, not pixels or any other unit of measurement - Scripts on the other hand have much broader utility.) Once you have the script written, you could map it to an F key, and export how ever many images/formats as you want with one tap.

If you feel like climbing that potentially steep learning curve, here's Adobe's own PDF guide:

https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/scripting/estk/adobe_intro_to_scripting.pdf